# how to test external css property using jasmin and karma

Tags: javascript, css, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

How to test external css property using `jasmine-karma`

```css
.buy{
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <span class="buy">
         Hello i want to check the width property
    </span>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? PLease mark it as an answer so that it can help others looking for similar problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't check `50` as a value but you can get the calculated `width` value using:

```
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    const e = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".test")).nativeElement;
    console.log(getComputedStyle(e).width)
   // you can get value as '442.5px' or something
  });
```

Not recommended to check such trivial property unless a must